# pylatexenc: How to manipulate nodes and write document from nodelist

Tags: python-3.x, latex

I want to read, manipulate and rewrite a tex document.

```
with open(self._filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  self._latexWalker = LatexWalker(file.read())

(nodelist, pos, len_) = self._latexWalker.get_latex_nodes(pos=0)
```

1. Question: How is the node properly manipulated?

my cumbersome solution to manipulate the node:

```
for node in nodelist:
  if(node.isNodeType(LatexEnvironmentNode)):
    if "document" in node.environmentname:
      j = 0
      for envNode in node.nodelist:
        if(envNode.isNodeType(LatexMacroNode)):
          if "recipient" in envNode.macroname:
            node.nodelist[j+1].nodelist[0].chars="Lorem ipsum" <---- does this make sense?
```

2. Question: How to write these nodelist to a tex-file?

i have no real idea except to iterate through the nodelist and write the blocks. But I am afraid that this is not a good idea. :)